# How do I load data from MongoDB to D3JS, with Jinja2 syntax?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, d3.js, flask, jinja2

I want to represent some entries in a list from my MongoDB database, but I want to use Jinja2 syntax, to get retrieve the entries from my database, through Flask. E.g.:

```
var dataArray = [{% for entry in entries %}{{ entry.value }}, {% endfor %}];

d3.select("body")
    ...
```

I think the comma is required, to seperate the values in the array, but it would still render a last comma, which is not needed. How does one do this properly?

Comment: Why do this in the template? Why not transform the array in code and then pass that to the template?

Comment: I want the snippet to be independent of my Flask code, so I can easily implement this. Then I only have to refer the list in Flask.

Comment: I decided to do what you said, and it works fairly good.

Answer (score 0):

On separate lines for clarity. It's still valid, but put all on one line if you wish.

```
var dataArray = [
{% for entry in entries -%}
   {{ entry.value }}
   {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{%- endfor %}
];
```